# Null exception in Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Before you search algorithm in the file manager.
What is wrong?

```
    import java.io.File;

public class SearchThread extends Thread {
    MainActivity ob = new MainActivity();
    Search ob2 = new Search();
    String searchString = new String();
    String stringDirectory = new String();
    public SearchThread(String string, String directory) {
        searchString = string;
        stringDirectory = directory;
        start();
    }

    public void run() {
        File directory = new File(stringDirectory);
        search(directory.listFiles());
    }
    public void search(File[] directory) {
        for(File a : directory) {
            if(a.isDirectory()) {
                search(a.listFiles());
            } else if(ob2.cutFormat(a.getName()) == searchString) {
                ob.giveMeString(a.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Message in log:

```
12-21 00:28:40.550  13147-13298/com.example.myproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-256
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.myproject.SearchThread.run(SearchThread.java:21)
12-21 00:28:40.558      471-482/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ #### captureScreenImplLocked
```

Line number 21: " `public void search(File[] directory) {`"
I pass from another class path from where to start as a string, and the string with the name of the item I'm looking for.

Comment: Could you please double check that line 21 is the `public void search(File[])` line (as opposed to something *in* that function)? Method declarations don't throw exceptions, as far as I know.

Comment: `MainActivity ob = new MainActivity();`. You can't do that. you have to use an instance of Activity provided by android, not created by you.

Comment: `==` does not work on Strings unless they point to the same object reference, java101

Comment: dear, MainActivity - it's name my Java Class :)

Comment: Do minimum things in constructor. *Effective Java*

Comment: exception stacktrace points to method `run`, I do not see code in method `run` that can throw NPE, check that you run the same code you have provided to us

Answer (score 0):

The listFiles() method in the File class can return null if `stringDirectory` does not actually point to a directory. Any other time it will return an empty array; so if this is returning null; your directory path is wrong.

Therefore the null exception is most probably occurring at the start your for-each loop:

`for (File a : directory)`

as you're calling your search(..) method directly with the listFiles() method.